# Unable to import snapshot meta file in YugabyteDB, table not found

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I’m getting the following error while importing the snapshot:

```
Error running import_snapshot: Invalid argument (yb/master/catalog_manager_ent.cc:1315): Unable to import snapshot meta file FOOBAR.snapshot: YSQL table not found: notes: OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (master error 3)
```

I am following this document - https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/manage/backup-restore/snapshot-ysql/#restore-a-snapshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After carefully reading the error, I realized it's failing for the table notes.

Schema import was failing because tservers were not distributed properly across the available AZs, once that got fixed.. it worked.